# Restaurant menu program TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'NoneType' and "NoneType"

Tags: python

Hi I am a Uni student that just started learning python. I am programming a restaurant menu that presents a menu and takes the users 'order' before calculating the Sub-total, GST (5% surcharge that is added onto the Sub-total) and Total of the order. I am getting a TypeError that starts on the "Sub-total line."

```
import math

#Substituting menu items.
m1 = "Green and Lean"
m2 = "Ginger Finger"
m3 = "Coffee Chaser"
m4 = "Berried Blended"
m5 = "Butter and Veggitmite Croissant"
m6 = "Pink Donut"
c1 = 4.50
c2 = 8.00
c3 = 2.50
c4 = 5.50
c5 = 8.00
c6 = 12.50

#Formatting and entering in menu items.
#Spacing with ' '*(x) 
#(' ') = white space and (x) = number of spaces
print("Welcome to Jeff and Jo's  Juice Bar!")                  
print()
print(m1 + ' '*33 + "$", c1)
print(m2 + ' '*34 + "$", c2)
print(m3 + ' '*34 + "$", c3)
print(m4 + ' '*32 + "$", c4)
print(m5 + ' '*16 + "$", c5)
print(m6 + ' '*37 + "$", c6)
print()

#User inputting oders.
o1 = input("Enter order for " + m1 + ": ")
o2 = input("Enter order for " + m2 + ": ")
o3 = input("Enter order for " + m3 + ": ")
o4 = input("Enter order for " + m4 + ": ")
o5 = input("Enter order for " + m5 + ": ")
o6 = input("Enter order for " + m6 + ": ")
print()

#Order spreadsheet
print("Order Summary")
s1 = print(m1 + ' '*34 + "$ 4.50 x ", o1)
s2 = print(m2 + ' '*35 + "$ 8.00 x ", o2)
s3 = print(m3 + ' '*35 + "$ 2.50 x ", o3)
s4 = print(m4 + ' '*33 + "$ 5.50 x ", o4)
s5 = print(m5 + ' '*17 + "$ 8.00 x ", o5)
s6 = print(m6 + ' '*38 + "$12.50 x ", o6)
print()

#Calculaiting "Sub-total" "GST" "Total".
print("Sub-total" + (s1 + s2 + s3 + s4 + s5 + s6))
print("GST" + ((s1 + s2 + s3 + s4 + s5 + s6) * 0.05 ))
print("Total")
```

Here is the output of the program.

```
Welcome to Guice's Juice Bar!

Green and Lean                                 $ 4.5
Ginger Finger                                  $ 8.0
Coffee Chaser                                  $ 2.5
Berried Blended                                $ 5.5
Butter and Veggitmite Croissant                $ 8.0
Pink Donut                                     $ 12.5

Enter order for Green and Lean: 0
Enter order for Ginger Finger: 0
Enter order for Coffee Chaser: 0
Enter order for Berried Blended: 1
Enter order for Butter and Veggitmite Croissant: 0
Enter order for Pink Donut: 1

Order Summary
Green and Lean                                  $ 4.50 x  0
Ginger Finger                                   $ 8.00 x  0
Coffee Chaser                                   $ 2.50 x  0
Berried Blended                                 $ 5.50 x  1
Butter and Veggitmite Croissant                 $ 8.00 x  0
Pink Donut                                      $12.50 x  1

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/order.py", line 55, in <module>
    print("Sub-total" + (s1 + s2 + s3 + s4 + s5 + s6))
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'NoneType' and 'NoneType'
```

Feel free to pitch in although I still have not attempted the last line(s) of the program. I also am confused on how c1-6 outputs with one decimal place instead of two decimals places. Thanks for the help in advance!

Comment: What do you think `s1 = print(...)` does? Remove that `print` or use it after you define `s1`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`print()` returns `None`, and you assign the results of that call to `s1`. Generally speaking, you shouldn't assign the result of `print()` to a variable.

You need to add code to compute the prices yourself. (This code could be made significantly more concise by using a data structure like a list or dictionary, but I have not made this modification to more clearly focus on the issue at hand.)

```py
#Order spreadsheet
print("Order Summary")
print(m1 + ' '*34 + "$ 4.50 x ", o1)
print(m2 + ' '*35 + "$ 8.00 x ", o2)
print(m3 + ' '*35 + "$ 2.50 x ", o3)
print(m4 + ' '*33 + "$ 5.50 x ", o4)
print(m5 + ' '*17 + "$ 8.00 x ", o5)
print(m6 + ' '*38 + "$12.50 x ", o6)
s1 = c1 * int(o1)
s2 = c2 * int(o2)
s3 = c3 * int(o3)
s4 = c4 * int(o4)
s5 = c5 * int(o5)
s6 = c6 * int(o6)
print()

#Calculaiting "Sub-total" "GST" "Total".
print("Sub-total: {:.2f}".format(s1 + s2 + s3 + s4 + s5 + s6))
print("GST: {:.2f}".format((s1 + s2 + s3 + s4 + s5 + s6) * 0.05))
print("Total")
```

Comment: Thanks so much I ended up getting it to work just fine! I appreciate the pointers. 
Regards.